# point grey camera withe jackal

Tags: ros, opencv, camera, jackal, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the jackal for my university project.

I have attached a camera to collect images and am using the cv bridge library to get snapshots.
On the desktop and simulation environment, I use the same camera and cv::bridge. I am able to see the images that are being captured because cv::window works.

I use ssh to log into the jackal and run my program.
Is there a way to make sure that the images are being taken and they are what I think they are?

For example, is there a way that I can enable the gui of the cv brigdge on the jackal and use CV window to see the images being taken and processed?

Please advise. Need help.
Regards,
rsmitha.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283445/point-grey-camera-withe-jackal/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you publish the images on the Jackal, you should be able to subscribe to them on your PC, and use something like `image_view` to display them.

Afaik the Jackal does not have any graphics hw.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0